# Managing global state (without singletons)

Tags: ios, swift

this is a fairly conceptual question so let me know if you want more detail.

For a high-level summary, I have a set of view controllers:

`HomeViewController` - This is the first VC in the app, and displays a list of data.

`ListViewController` - Presented by `HomeViewController`, shows the same list of data described in HomeViewController, but just presented slightly differently.

`AddViewController` - Presented by `ListViewController`, adds items that are displayed on the list.

When the user finishes adding an item in `AddViewController`, I've coded it to pop the `AddViewController`, and used `viewDidAppear` on `ListViewController` to reload the list on `ListViewController` to reflect the new item.

Now, the question - popping `ListViewController` leads back to `HomeViewController`, which I'd also like to update. Now - I can use `viewDidAppear` again but, in order to not kill the server I'd like to have some system that says "only update if you need to".

The obvious solution is to have a singleton state management system for each view. Hold some dict of "hasUpdated" views and pass a view ID in (maybe a hash of the VC) and that will say whether or not to poll the server or cache.

I've been doing iOS for a while now and know that Singletons are considered an anti-pattern.

The other solution is to carry some kind of 'isDirty' state on each view controller and intercept the pop action to call a closure if required...this just seems so verbose! A global state management system would be easier to understand and read, but has a whole host of problems.

This just seems like such a simple thing to do - I think I've not seen this problem before because I only really worked on one-way apps (i.e. app downloads and shows data, rather than the user changing the data).

Any ideas?

Comment: _I've been doing iOS for a while now and know that Singletons are considered an anti-pattern_ - only by those who don't really understand the concept of Singleton. It's by no means an anti-pattern, there are obvious cases (like yours, for instance) where Singleton is the best logical solution. Besides, several Cocoa framework classes are singletons. Like any other design pattern, Singleton has it's uses, and like all design patterns, it can be used or implemented incorrectly.

Comment: I've seen several leading figures in the iOS community denounce singletons as an anti-pattern... being pragmatic I think they probably have a fairly good understanding of the concept. My main worry is about testability. I could inject it into the classes one level up I suppose.

Comment: Care to share a source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different way to achieve it. And it also depends on how you keep data in the local cache.

For instance, if you use Core Data, you can observe any changes for a specific type of Entity and perform a reload for the corresponding Cell Row, adding / deleting a Cell Row and so on.

If the data is simpler, perhaps saved inside an array - I'd create a StateController object and it will contain the Array property and perform operations on it. You can use Closures or Delegate Protocol methods to communicate back to any of the view controller that gets hooked-up to it.

Comment: But wouldn't that StateController end up being a singleton? The issue I have is that it's difficult to pass it around as it'd need to go three controllers deep.

Comment: Not really. Technically, you will have one instance in memory, but the class itself is not a Singleton.

Comment: You can also use the Coordinator Pattern. Let each View Controller have an property of State Controller type. Let the coordinator instantiate the State Controller object and inject it to every View Controller. The coordinator may also keep track if some specific View Controller's UI is "up-to-date" or it should perform an update.

Comment: (Regarding my first comment in this thread) The State Controller object should be created in some place like App Delegate and injected to Home View Controller. Then it should propagate to the other ones.

Comment: Yeah so this is more or less how I'm doing it actually. I'm using Flow Coordinators to create and manage my dependencies and view controller.

The issue is passing the state controller forward and back through the flow coordinators, as they all conform to a "FlowCoordinator" protocol which implements a "pushViewController:" function that doesn't know about my state controllers (there could be many different types of view controller I push, some will use that state controller, some will use others, so the pushViewController function is generic).

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/model-controllers-in-swift

The idea is similar to what I've stated above. We need to inject the Model / State to each view controller. And we should apply the Observer Pattern so the Model Controller would notify any observer about its internal changes.

Comment: Also: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/global-state-and-dependency-injection-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much want there to be only one instance of your data model; otherwise you end up with the potential for inconsistency.

Two common approaches are a singleton or a single instance that you pass to each VC (a dependency injection pattern).

The disadvantage of the Singleton approach is it can impact testability; Since each object that uses the Singleton has an explicitly invocation of `Something.shared` it is difficult to mock `Something`.

The advantage is that you don't need to modify the initialisation process or even add properties to your object if you don't want; you can just grab the Singleton instance when you need it.

Also, the singleton pattern enforces the rule that there can only ever be one *instance* of the object.

With dependency injection you can instantiate `MockSomething` and because this object gets passed to each consuming object, those consumers are not aware that they are dealing with a mocking subclass of `Something`.

The downside is that true DI is tricky with `UIViewController`s as you can't change the initialiser signature to include the dependency. This means you end up with an optional or implicitly unwrapped optional for the `Something` reference, which you may or may not like.

You really need to evaluate on a case-by-case basis rather than simply discarding the use of Singletons.

A model object that you don't need to mock may be fine as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem reduces to the communication between 1 object (the Model) to N objects (the ViewControllers).

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The most common solution in iOS is to use [Notifications through the NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter).  Also, you could try to implement patterns like [Observation](https://medium.com/@samstone/design-patterns-in-swift-observer-pattern-51274d34f9e3), so the *Observers* (ViewControllers) will suscribe to *observe* changes on a Subject (Model).

Comment: And by the way, if you go with NotificationCenter, you will be using a Singleton with the responsibility to broadcast notifications to objects, nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the Notification Center is another one of those things that Apple gives you, but is just so brittle and untestable. I honestly think whatever I do, it's going to need a singleton of some kind. I'll just try to inject it as high up as possible to keep the app as testable as possible.

Comment: I would not recommend to use NotificationCenter, because it may lead to unmaintainable code, especially if the code becomes big.